# How to use ASC 2.0 with FlashDevelop 4.4 for inline functions?

Tags: actionscript-3, inline, flashdevelop

Up until now I used Aparat for inline funcs.
I am new to ASC 2.0 and FlashDevelop 4.4
I wish to create a swf file that uses ASC 2.0 inline functions as described here:
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4789

If there is a tutorial ready, please direct me to the right place (I am doing LD and don't have much time to search).

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Project >> Properties >> SDK

   - Pick AIR 3.7.0
2. Go to Project >> Properties >> Additional Compiler Options

   - click on the `+`
   - Add the line `-inline` and press enter